# When does django-allauth social account extra data get updated?

Tags: django, twitter, django-allauth

if a minute has gone by and the user has updated his status on twitter will django-allauth update this on my app (async) or do I have to update this info manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) only updates `SocialAccount.extra_data` by default in two scenarios; during the initial signup and [during the completion](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py#L136) of a subsequent login. Neither of these are done asynchronously.

If you want to update Twitter data behind the scenes, you can use the stored SocialToken for the user's Twitter account (if it hasn't yet expired!) to hit up Twitter's API as needed. You could drive this with a cronjob and/or an asynchronous queue such that web requests are not impacted.